# Merging two msi using wix toolset

Tags: wix, wix3.7

How to merge two msi using wixedit, presently they are having 4.0 version of wixtoolset. In the documentation they have mentioned that merging two msi in windows is possible using bundles and chain tags. But whenver I try to do it, it always show some error. Please let me know any example of wix tool set to merge two msi using bundle and chain tags.

I am following Bootstrapper method as provided in pdf of wix 3.6. To bundle two msi using chain element.

Comment: WixEdit is for one MSI. You need to follow the bundle path. You what you have done so far.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Bundle Name="Awesome Software"
Version="1.0.0.0"
Manufacturer="Awesome Company"
UpgradeCode="c352f5c7-1dbe-416c-820d-685b058270d5">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef
Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
<Chain>
<!--TODO: Define the list of chained packages.-->
</Chain>
</Bundle>
</Wix>                   I am following this method as provided in documentation part.

Comment: Obviously the TODO: should be replaced by something meaningful. Could you add this to the question.

Comment: add the bundle code to the question and also the error that you are getting. "Show some error" is not really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Bundle Name="Prog" Version="0.0.0.1" Manufacturer="my Corporation" UpgradeCode="f380ae43-5df1-4cfe-9297-526e3e333e99">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="..\license.rtf" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx45FullPackage" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx45FullPackage">
      <MsiPackage Id="Prog" Cache="no" Compressed="no" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.installerPath)\Prog.msi" />
      <MsiPackage Id="Prog2" Cache="no" Compressed="no" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.installerPath)\Prog2.msi" />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

you can add the variable installerPath
[image]

Comment: candle.exe : error CNDL0001 : The 'bootstrapperApplicationData' attribute is not declared.

Exception Type: System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException

Comment: Actually i am using wixedit tool for this wxs file and adding command line argument and extension WixBalExtension.dll to compile using candle and light exe

Comment: you need to use a bootstarpper project

Comment: please tell me how to make bootstarpper project?

Comment: should i use visual studio for that ??

Comment: i.e merging two msi is not possible using wixedit but it is given there documents that it is possible using wixedit or wix-toolset also.